# Wordpress user conditional tags

Tags: wordpress, if-statement, tags, conditional-statements

How can i make wordpress user conditional tags something like this

```
<?php if (current user has fill first_name field()){ ?>
your info is complete
<?php } else { ?>
you need to fill first_name field
<?php } ?>
```

please help me, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `get_the_author_meta()` function get the user meta and `get_current_user_id()` to get the current user id.

```
<?php
if ( get_the_author_meta( 'user_firstname', get_current_user_id() ) ) {
    echo 'your info is complete';
} else {
    echo 'you need to fill first_name field';
}
```

Reference: [get_the_author_meta()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_author_meta/) [get_current_user_id()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_current_user_id/)